# How to use perl’s uri_encode in one line

Tags: html, macos, perl, html-entities

In the past I’ve used the code `echo "&lt;one two&gt;" | perl -MHTML::Entities -ne 'print decode_entities($_)'` to output `<one two>`.

Now I want to do something similar, but I want to encode it in a way that `echo "one two" | *perl magic*` outputs `one+two`, or maybe `one%20two`.

I’d like a command that’d do this kind of url encode on the whole string, that could be piped, like the first example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing this using the *proper module* =)

```
$ echo 'one two' | perl -MURI::Escape -wlne 'print uri_escape $_'
one%20two
```

See [URI::Escape doc](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape)

### Note

If you need something faster, consider using [URI::Escape::XS](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape%3a%3aXS)

Comment: 100% agreed — but the difficulty is finding the name of the correct module.

Comment: Exactly. I was trying `MURI::Encode` (I’m not a big perl user). That said, it’s exactly what I wanted. Thank you.